# Why does FakeFS break RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

**test_spec.rb:** (from FakeFS [example](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs#rspec))

```
require 'fakefs/spec_helpers' 

describe 'Test' do
  include FakeFS::SpecHelpers
  it 'should fail' do
    expect(1).to eq(2)
  end
end

describe 'Test2' do
  it 'should fail' do
    expect(1).to eq(2)
  end
end
```

**rspec spec/test_spec.rb** returns `superclass mismatch for class File` for the first test and normal `expected: 2 got: 1` in the second case. Matcher changing (e.g. `be_kind_of(String)`) does not affect the result. Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

**ruby -v**

```
ruby 2.4.0dev (2016-03-19 trunk 54188) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: see: https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs/issues/215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this issue, and the accepted answer did not help me.

But I did eventually solve the issue by adding the following line to the top of my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'pp'
```

I have a `.rspec` file with the following line to ensure spec_helper is loaded always:

```
--require spec_helper
```

It is documented in the FakeFS readme that you need to require `pp` before `fakefs` in order to avoid this problem, but I did not require `pp` myself. It must have been required implicitly by some other gem I use*.

Thus by explicitly requiring `pp` before `fakefs`, my specs now run as they should.

*  I suspect RSpec uses `pp` for pretty printing error messages, as I could cause the exception in the line `expect(true).to eq false`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @d.g for [link](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs/issues/215) to fakefs issue. Things that works:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'fakefs', require: 'fakefs/safe'
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FakeFS::SpecHelpers, fakefs: true
end
```

**test_spec.rb**

```
require_relative 'spec_helper.rb'

describe 'Test', fakefs: true do
  it 'should fail' do
    expect(1).to be_kind_of(String)
  end
end
```